How to check for a quick flat-hand touch of a touch-screen (Smartphone)
For my desktop browser I created a Javascript/Jquery program with lots of information and music files as well.
I made it so, that when I press the spacebar, the sound stops or resumes.
To my knowledge this is the general way most programs handle sound or video.
I needed this toggle, so that when somebody comes in, or there is a phone call, I can quickly and easily pause the music.
Recently I ported this program to run on Smartphones, and here I wonder what I can use as alternative for the spacebar. Swiping in any direction is no option, because that already handles other things.
Haven’t found a consensus how this (toggling the sound) is handled, could of course program a button to do that, but my idea is that on touchscreens there are ‘better’ options, so I came up with the idea to pause (and restart) the sound by a quick touch with my whole hand flat on the screen.
Have used touch events for 1 and 2 fingers, but haven’t come across a (say around 90%) complete screencovering touch.
Does something like that exist ?
Don’t need a complete piece of code, just an idea on how to implement this or whether there are 'ready-made' alternatives.
Thanks in advance !

Unclear if you've seen: HTML5 canvas, palm rejection as your question doesn't include which Web APIs you've tested.

@Morrison Chang: Thank you, didn't came across radiusX and radiusY (yet), but will certainly experiment with it a bit.  Thanks again !!

@Morrison Chang: Found a solution via chatPCT   I asked the question:   "Javascript, jquery, css, smartphone how to check whether at least 60% of screen is touched (hidden) by my hand"   and it came up with the following solution:      Hmm, wanted to copy and paste the solution, but this comment field only has 300 characters left, and the html, js and css far exceed that.    Anyway, I found a working solution and will now implement this in my own code.  Just thought to let you know.
